# fork generating incorrect output for this c program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork

I have this c code

```
/* SIGCHLD handler. */
static void sigchld_hdl (int sig)
{
    /* Wait for all dead processes.
     * We use a non-blocking call to be sure this signal handler will not
     * block if a child was cleaned up in another part of the program. */
     //printf("Inside handler:  \n");
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0) {
        printf("reaped\n");
    }
     //printf("Outside handler:  \n");

}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sigaction act;
    int i;

    memset (&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = sigchld_hdl;

    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0)) {
        perror ("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    /* Make some children. */
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        switch (fork()) {
            case -1:
                perror ("fork");
                return 1;
            case 0:
                 exit(0);
                return 0;
            default:
                //printf("inside parent\n");
                printf("Created child %d\n", i);

        }
    }

    /* Wait until we get a sleep() call that is not interrupted by a signal. */
    while (sleep(1)) {
        printf("inside parent while loop\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am calling fork 5 times, so I expect total 5 child process and 1 parent process. When I run this code, I get this output

```
Created child 0
Created child 1
reaped
reaped
Created child 2
Created child 3
Created child 3
reaped
reaped
Created child 4
reaped
inside parent while loop
```

I can't quite figure out why I am seeing child3 twice. There should not be any duplication with regards to i as i is incrementing in every iteration.

Can somebody explain why I am seeing child3 twice?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. You shouldn't call `printf()` in a signal handler, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: @Barmar why shouldn't I call printf in handler. You have to run it a few time to reproduce.

Comment: It's not async-safe. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891019/how-to-avoid-using-printf-in-a-signal-handler

Comment: I ran it about 10 times

Comment: Do you redirect output when you're testing it, or is output to a terminal?

Comment: @Barmar I can reproduce it quite easily. Does it have something to do with print/buffer>

Comment: @Barmar I am printing on the terminal?

Comment: If output isn't to a terminal, stdio is buffered, so you need to call `fflush(stdout)` after you print. But if you're printing to the terminal, it automatically flushes whenever you print `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

The state of the stdio buffers is contained in the process's memory space. If the buffers are not empty at the time of a fork, the parent and child both have a copy of the information that says `"Child process 3\n"` is in the stdout buffer, waiting to be flushed.

And they will both eventually flush it.

You can avoid this by calling `_exit` instead of `exit` in the child process. `exit` is usually a bad idea when you're in a process that has not completed a successful exec since it was created.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your debugging output. It's undefined behavior to call printf in your async signal handler. There's only a short list of functions guaranteed to be safe during a signal handler.

If you remove it, you'll see the one outside of the signal handler never has unexpected behavior.

Comment: I am getting unexpected behavior for the code in the main, not the handler. Created child is from the parent processx.

Comment: It doesn't matter where the symptom appears.